# How to run OS X from DVD or USB stick?

Tags: startup, unix, macos

I would like to have a safe "Linux-like start/boot from DVD or USB stick" environment.

How to do such security thing for the latest OS X (10.9 Mavericks)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to make a live environment from a DVD, but it is relatively easy to do it with an USB flash drive or an external HDD.

To install it to your HDD or flash drive do the following:

- connect your drive
- open the "Disk Utility" and click on the corresponding drive on the left hand side
- click on the partition tab and select 1 partition from the drop-down menu
- click on options and make sure you'll format it with the GUID Partition Table in order to make the drive bootable

  - **BE VERY SURE ABOUT THIS, YOU'LL ERASE EVERYTHING ON THE HARDDRIVE**
- now mount your install image and proceed with the installation, be sure to select the proper harddrive

Also, note that you already have a recovery partition.

Comment: You can choose your startup disk by pressing the Option/Alt key just after the startup chime. This way you can switch between operating systems.